# c# difference for two list of range periods

Tags: c#, algorithm, date, date-range, difference

Can you help me with an algoritm who make the difference between two sets of range periods.

For example:

*First set of range periods*:
{[01.01.2015 - 10.01.2015] , [15.01.2015 - 30.01.2015]}

*The second set of range periods*:
{[02.01.2015 - 20.01.2015] , [25.01.2015 - 25.01.2015]}

*The result should be*:
{[01.01.2015 - 01.01.2015] , [21.01.2015 - 24.01.2015], [26.01.2015-30.01.2015]}

This is my code so far:

```
        private object GetDifferenceRangePeriods(List<RangePeriod> all, List<RangePeriod> toRemove)
    {
        foreach (var rp in toRemove)
        {
            var overlappedItems = all.Where(c => DateHelper.IsOverlapping(c.StartDate, c.EndDate, rp.StartDate, rp.EndDate)).ToList();
            foreach (var itm in overlappedItems)
            {
                if (itm.StartDate == rp.StartDate)
                {
                    if (itm.EndDate <= rp.EndDate)
                    {
                        all.Remove(itm);
                    }
                    else if(itm.EndDate > rp.EndDate)
                    {
                        itm.StartDate = rp.EndDate.AddDays(+1);
                    }
                }

                if (itm.StartDate < rp.StartDate)
                {
                    if (itm.EndDate <= rp.EndDate)
                    {
                        itm.EndDate = rp.StartDate.AddDays(-1);
                    }
                    if (itm.EndDate > rp.EndDate)
                    {
                        itm.EndDate= rp.StartDate.AddDays(-1);

                        var newRangePeriod = new RangePeriod
                        {
                            StartDate = rp.EndDate.AddDays(+1),
                            EndDate = itm.EndDate
                        };
                        all.Add(newRangePeriod);
                    }
                }

                if (itm.StartDate > rp.StartDate)
                {
                    if (itm.EndDate <= rp.EndDate)
                    {
                        all.Remove(itm);
                    }
                    if (itm.EndDate > rp.EndDate)
                    {
                        itm.StartDate = itm.EndDate.AddDays(+1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return all;
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear! Can you share some code? and what did you try?

Comment: Is the first set include ranges, and the second set exclude ranges?  Might want to state that in the question if so.

Comment: @ebyrob I think that's what the OP meant by difference, as in set one minus set two.

Comment: Now that you've shared some code can you be more specific about the exact part that is giving you a problem?  Maybe you could tell just what the results are for your current code.

Comment: Why is your method returning `object` instead of `List<RangePeriod>`?  Also you should really be creating a new list of new ranges instead of mutating the `all` list that was passed in.

Comment: I don't like  my alghoritm because is very hard to read and to understand it. I want to find a short solution more readeable and more simple.

Comment: Thanks for your sugestions @juharr

Comment: @Otix Are you saying your current algorithm works, but you just want a more elegant solution?  If so, your question would be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd do this with a lazy initialization approach.

```
public static IEnumerable<RangePeriod> Minus(
    this IEnumerable<RangePeriod> first,
    IEnumerable<RangePeriod> second)
{
    // First make sure that the lists are ordered by their start dates.
    var firstSorted = first.OrderBy(r => r.StartDate);
    var secondSorted = second.OrderBy(r => r.StartDate);

    // get the enumerators of the sorted sequences.
    using (var keep = firstSorted.GetEnumerator())
    using (var remove = secondSorted.GetEnumerator())
    {
        // if there are no ranges to keep then return an empy sequence.
        if (!keep.MoveNext()) yield break;
        var currentKeep = keep.Current;
        RangePeriod currentRemove = null;
        if (remove.MoveNext()) currentRemove = remove.Current;
        while (true)
        {
            // if there are no more remove ranges or the remove range is after the keep
            // then just yield the keep range and move to the next keep range.
            if (currentRemove == null || currentKeep.EndDate < currentRemove.StartDate)
            {
                yield return currentKeep;
                if (!keep.MoveNext()) yield break;
                currentKeep = keep.Current;
                continue;
            }

            // if the remove range is before the keep then move to the next remove range.
            if (currentRemove.EndDate < currentKeep.StartDate)
            {
                currentRemove = remove.MoveNext() ? remove.Current : null;
                continue;
            }

            // if the remove range ends before the keep range
            if (currentRemove.EndDate < currentKeep.EndDate)
            {
                // if the keep starts before the remove then we yield a range from the keep's start
                // to the remove's start - 1 day.
                if (currentKeep.StartDate < currentRemove.StartDate)
                {
                    yield return new RangePeriod(currentKeep.StartDate, currentRemove.StartDate.AddDays(-1));
                }

                // change the keep's start to the remove's end + 1 and move to the next remove range.
                currentKeep = new RangePeriod(currentRemove.EndDate.AddDays(1), currentKeep.EndDate);
                currentRemove = remove.MoveNext() ? remove.Current : null;
                continue;
            }

            // if the remove range completely covers the keep then move to the next keep (if there is one)
            if (currentRemove.StartDate < currentKeep.StartDate)
            {
                if (!keep.MoveNext()) yield break;
                currentKeep = keep.Current;
                continue;
            }

            // Otherwise the remove range starts after the keep starts but before the keep ends and the
            // remove ends after the keep ends, so we need to yield a range that starts on the keep's
            // start and ends before the remove's start and move to the next keep range.
            yield return new RangePeriod(currentKeep.StartDate, currentRemove.StartDate.AddDays(-1));
            if (!keep.MoveNext()) yield break;
            currentKeep = keep.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

That will allow you to do the following

```
var first = new[]
            {
                new RangePeriod(new DateTime(2015, 1, 1), new DateTime(2015, 1, 10)),
                new RangePeriod(new DateTime(2015, 1, 15), new DateTime(2015, 1, 30))
            };
var second = new[]
            {
                new RangePeriod(new DateTime(2015, 1, 2), new DateTime(2015, 1, 20)),
                new RangePeriod(new DateTime(2015, 1, 25), new DateTime(2015, 1, 25))
            };

foreach(var range in first.Minus(second)) 
    Console.WriteLine($"{range.StartDate} to {range.EndDate}");
```

And get these results

> 1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM to 1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM
>
> 1/21/2015 12:00:00 AM to 1/24/2015 12:00:00 AM
>
> 1/26/2015 12:00:00 AM to 1/30/2015 12:00:00 AM